# Is it possible to convert a text that's in the form of a changelog from oldest-first into newest-first, using vim?

Tags: vim, text-editors

Is it possible to convert a text that's in the form of a changelog 
into newest-first, using vim?

It's like this:

```
version 1.0

multi_line description for 1.0


version 1.01

multi_line description for 1.01

etc
```

and I want to convert it into

```
version 1.90

multi_line description for 1.90


version 1.89

multi_line description for 1.89

etc
```

The text is really too long to convert it manually.

PS. "multi_line description" eg:

```
Added feature x
Fixed bug y
Removed element z
Updated file z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you just want to reverse the order, not re-sort.

This works in my small test:

```
:g/^version/,/\nversion\|\%$/m0
```

This assumes that any line beginning with "version" is the start of a section you want to keep together.  A simpler way to do it is to add a dummy line containing just "version" at the end of the file, then

```
:g/^version/,//-m0
```

ignore the error message, and remove the dummy line.

Either way, this tells vim to execute `[range]m0` on every line matching `^version`.  The command `m0` or `:move 0` moves the indicated lines to the start of the file.

In the second version, the range goes from the current line (the one matching `^version`) to the next matching line, minus 1.  If you can spare an extra two characters, add the dot and the 1:  `.,//-1` is equivalent to `,//-`.

The first version I gave cooks up a more complex pattern to deal with the fact that, on the last match, the search for the next match will fail.  In a vim pattern, `\%$` refers to the last line or EOF.

Comment: The 1st version works like a charm.
Thanks a lot for the help!